# Error on new build template after migration from TFS2012 to TFS2013

Tags: iis, tfs, migration

I recently migrated from TFS2012 to a brand new hardware running TFS2013. I was using a slightly customized template to build and deploy my solutions to IIS. They still work ok on TFS2013. Now I want to use the new template "TfvcTemplate.12.xaml" so I setup a new build. When I try to execute it I get this error:

```
TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \MyProject\Build_Test: 
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

The exception is:

> `Inner Exception Details:
>   Exception Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.1.1.10:8080 (type SocketException)`

```
Exception Stack Trace:    
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

That IP address "192.1.1.10" corresponds to the old server (TFS2012), which is wrong. It seems like there's still some configuration remaining from the migration, pointing to the previous server. Keep in mind the migrated templates build just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you upgrade/configure a new build controller when you migrated? If so, did you ensure that the new build controller was selected when you created the build?

Comment: Yes, I created a build controller from scratch on the new box. I de-registered the old controller (so that it doesn't show up anymore) and shut down the old server. I created a new build definition from scratch, using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml template, pointing to the new Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reinstall the Controller and Re-Select it in the build-Definition
2. Please Check in Visual Studio under "Build" -->Actions\ManageBuildControllers... that your Controller is available
3. Ensure that your Controller is set in the "Queue new build"-Action.
4. You can try to create an empty workflow (With a write to build Message - Activity) to check the connection to your Controller

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Oswald. Registering a new controller fixed it.